# HTML Local Storage Icon Change and Dark Mode with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, local-storage

I have made a dark mode button with my own dark theme. The theme is saved by Local Storage. Also when I click the button, then it's icon change (moon to sun). But if I reload the page, the site is still in dark mode but the button icon's is the moon again. So heres a link which show you the problem if youo don't understant what i am talking about. (https://postimg.cc/yg6Q3vq0)
Also heres my code:

```js
//This is the darkmode script. 
function darkmode() {
  const wasDarkmode = localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true';
  localStorage.setItem('darkmode', !wasDarkmode);
  const element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle('dark-mode', !wasDarkmode);

}
function onload() {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode', localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true');
}
//End
//And this is the code which change the button's icon
$('button').on('click', fav);

function fav(e) {
  $(this).find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-moon-o fa-sun-o');
}
//So I would like to combine the 2 codes. I mean to add the icon code to Local Storage.
```

```css
.card {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: blue;
  
}

.dark-mode .car {
  color: blue;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a style="padding: 0 !important;"><button class="darkmode" onclick="darkmode()"><i class="fa fa-moon-o"></i></button></a>

<div class="card">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Text<//p>
<h2>Another text..</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser just renders the HTML as written. Your HTML says to render `<i class="fa fa-moon-o"></i>`, so that's what the browser shows. In other words, it will always show the moon icon by default.

You need to perform some kind of check on page load to see if the icon should be changed.

Something like this might work:

```
// when the document is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    // check if dark mode is enabled
    if (localStorage.getItem('darkmode') === 'true') {
        // if it is, change the moon icon to a sun icon
        ('.fa').toggleClass('fa-moon-o fa-sun-o');
    }
});
```